# bash: use different input streams for loop condition and body

Tags: bash, io-redirection, file-descriptors

i have a script with a while loop like this:

```
while IFS= read -r name; do
    {body}
done < names.txt
```

the loop condition needs to read names from a file, but `{body}` needs to read from stdin; the above script will make `{body}` read from the file, which is a mistake;

i can get around with another fd:

```
while IFS= read -r name <&3; do
    {body}
done 3< names.txt
```

questions:

1. is this the best solution?
2. is it safe/recommended to use file descriptor 3? will a higher fd number give less chance to cause a conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a separate file descriptor for the `read` command is a good solution.

You are guaranteed that file descriptors between 3 and 9 will be available to you for doing this.  The shell will not use these for anything else. Only file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 have predefined uses, and you *may* find that using descriptors with values larger than 9 works, but there is no such guarantee.

The [POSIX standard says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07):

> Open files are represented by decimal numbers starting with zero. The largest possible value is implementation-defined; however, **all implementations shall support at least 0 to 9, inclusive, for use by the application.** These numbers are called "file descriptors". **The values 0, 1, and 2 have special meaning** and conventional uses and are implied by certain redirection operations; they are referred to as standard input, standard output, and standard error, respectively.

Using file descriptors above 9 may be hazardous, depending on which number and shell you use:

- `bash` uses fd 255 internally.
- `zsh`, `dash` and `pdksh` uses fd 10 internally.
- `ksh93` appears to use fd 3 (but this seems like a bug, it's connected to the directory that serves as the mount point of the current filesystem).